# What exactly is a "Null reply" in Redis?

Tags: scala, redis

I use Redis with Scala ([rediscala](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala) library). I need to create a transaction like this:

```
redisTransaction.watch(key)
redisTransaction.zremrangebyscore(key, limit, limit) *>
redisTransaction.zadd(key, (someValue, entry)) *>
redisTransaction.set[ByteString](s"$lastSeqNumKey", sequenceNum) *>
redisTransaction.exec().void
```

The last expression should return a `Future[Unit]` which I expect to fail in case of failed transaction. However, Redis documentation states that:

> When using WATCH, EXEC can return a Null reply if the execution was aborted.

What exactly is a "null reply"? Is it possible that my `Future[Unit]` will succeed with a `null` value, or empty String or something similar? I'd like to write a test and I need some hints about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One correction, there is no `void` method on `redisTransaction.exec()`.

**Short answer:**

`exec()` call will return `Future(MultiBulk(None))` if the transaction fails or the execution is aborted.

**Long answer:**

As the documentation says,

> When using WATCH, EXEC can return a Null reply if the execution was
>   aborted.

and links to [NULL reply](https://redis.io/topics/protocol#nil-reply) 's explanation

> RESP Bulk Strings can also be used in order to signal non-existence of
>   a value using a special format that is used to represent a Null value.
>   In this special format the length is -1, and there is no data, so a
>   Null is represented as:
>
> `"$-1\r\n"` This is called a Null Bulk String.
>
> The client library API should not return an empty string, but a nil
>   object, when the server replies with a Null Bulk String. For example a
>   Ruby library should return 'nil' while a C library should return NULL
>   (or set a special flag in the reply object), and so forth

This points to the fact that server will reply with a NULL response and the client has to deal with it. It can't be an empty string and in this library it is dealt to decode & map the response from server as `MultiBulk(None)`

There is a [test case](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala/blob/f1c1101a87ebe858f7bcd6b4222e4698c06524df/src/test/scala/redis/protocol/RedisProtocolReplySpec.scala#L72) for the decoding of NULL responses from redis.

Comment: Thanks! As for the `.void` method, it's a `Functor` extension from Cats library, basically transforming `F[A]` to `F[Unit]`. I used it because I expected the `Future` to fail for failed transaction, but I'll drop it in order to check for `MultiBulk(None)` now.

Comment: Aah okay, you are using cats. I realized it now when I saw the *> operator. Anyway I hope my answer helps.